# Array with None Values Changes to Float Number When Loading into Pandas Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an array which looks like

```py
[None, None, None,101, 555, 756, 924, 485]
```

When I load it into a `pandas` column they change to float number (I guess because of `None` values)

```py
import pandas as pd

the_array = [None, None, None, 101, 555, 756, 924, 485]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['request'])
df['request'] = the_array

print(df)
```

The output looks like

```py
   request
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3    101.0
4    555.0
5    756.0
6    924.0
7    485.0
```

Can you please let me know how to fix this? Basically what I need is

```
   request
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      101
4      555
5      756
6      924
7      485
```

Comment: The column is inevitably type float because of the NaN values. You can change the way floats are displayed using for example `pd.set_option("display.precision", 0)` which gets what you want. Alternatively but more complicated, you could change the various values to Strings modified to display as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [`pandas` 1.0.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html) the [`pd.NA`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.NA.html#pandas.NA) dtype was introduced to [handle things like this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html). Using [`pd.Int64Dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Int64Dtype.html#pandas.Int64Dtype) or similar, you can keep your integers and the nulls will be replaced with [`pd.NA`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.NA.html#pandas.NA).

```py
import pandas as pd

the_array = [None, None, None, 101, 555, 756, 924, 485]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=the_array,
    columns=["request"],
    dtype="Int64",  # string alias for `pd.Int64Dtype()`
)
print(df)
```

```py
   request
0     <NA>
1     <NA>
2     <NA>
3      101
4      555
5      756
6      924
7      485
```

## Resources

- [Working with missing data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html)
- [Integer dtypes and missing data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html#integer-dtypes-and-missing-data)
- [Support for integer `NA`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na)
- [`pandas.Int64Dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Int64Dtype.html#pandas.Int64Dtype)
- [`pandas.NA`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.NA.html#pandas.NA)
- [Experimental `NA` scalar to denote missing values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#experimental-na-scalar-to-denote-missing-values)
- [What’s new in 1.0.0 (January 29, 2020)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html)